# How to print to stderr in fish shell?

Tags: shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection, fish

In a fish-shell script, how do you print an error message to stderr?

For example, this message should go to the stderr stream rather than the default stdout stream.

```
echo "Error: $argv[1] is not a valid option"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can redirect the output to stderr, for example:

```
echo "Error: $argv[1] is not a valid option" 1>&2
```

---

As a reference, here are some common IO-redirections that work in fish*.

```
foo 1>&2 # Redirects stdout to stderr, same as bash

bar 2>&1 # Redirects stderr to stdout, same as bash

bar ^&1  # Redirects stderr to stdout, the fish way using a caret ^
```

<sup>* The file descriptors for stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2.

* The `&` implies you want to redirect to a file stream instead of a file.

* [Comparison of redirection in various shells](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#redirection) (bash, fish, ksh, tcsh, zsh)</sup>

Comment: You don’t need the `1` – just adding `>&2` works too, because redirecting from stdout is the default. (No spaces allowed – `> &2` does not work.)

Comment: This should be marked as the Answer, I found it very helpful!